# Enable APC only for specific directories?

Tags: php, linux, caching, centos, apc

I currently have APC installed and running on a CentOs server, it's working fine however it currently caches all files in all directories.

How can I change the settings so that it only caches directories I choose?

So for example I could enable it one directory using .htaccess?

The only APC settings I currently have in my `php.ini` are the following:

```
extension = apc.so
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_size = 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **apc.filters string**
>
> A comma-separated list of POSIX extended regular expressions. If any pattern matches the source filename, the file will not be cached. Note that the filename used for matching is the one passed to include/require, not the absolute path. If the first character of the expression is a + then the expression will be additive in the sense that any files matched by the expression will be cached, and if the first character is a - then anything matched will not be cached. The - case is the default, so it can be left off.

This is a PHP_INI_SYSTEM parameter so you can only do this on a per dir basis *if* you are are running under cgi/suEXEC/suPHP and can set your php.ini on a per dir basis.

Comment: So `/home/user([^6])/.*` would stop everything apart from `/home/user6/` from being cached?

Comment: How about `/home/user63/fred.php`? So no. However, looking at the source (am I sad for having it on my PC), APC uses the PHP PCRE engine so you should be able to do negative lookahead assertions such as `^(?!/home/user6/).*`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apc.filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters) to tell APC to not cache certain files/directories. The matching is done by regular expression.